# Mutating File at S3 Bucket w/ AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Given an S3 file at `s3://path/to/bucket/file`, I'd like to execute an AWS Lambda Function that appends "BAR".

To clarify, let's say that a file containing "FOO" lives at `s3://path/to/bucket/file`. I'd like to execute a JavaScript function that appends "BAR".

So, after mutating the file at the S3 file location, the contents of `s3://path/to/bucket/file` would read, "FOOBAR".

How can I do this?

Comment: You do realize that S3 objects are not files, and can't be appended-to, right? The only operation available in S3 is overwrite/replace.  The only way to accomplish this is to fetch the object, modify it in memory or on local disk, and upload the newly changed object to S3.

Comment: be careful to do this in the same bucket cause s3 will produce a new event and "loop is coming"

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @Casper - I ended up using AWS Lambda to listen on `bucket1` for insertion events. Upon inserting an object into `bucket1`, AWS Lambda would copy the object from `bucket1` to `bucket2`, applying a function to the copied `object` (I was using JSON) to add a new `key-value` pair to the JSON. I did this back in the beginning of 2015. For me, I found the AWS Lambda docs to be difficult to read. However, that was roughly 1 1/2 years ago, so maybe they've improved.

Comment: I also desire this sadly missing functionality

Answer (score 2):

in your s3.getObject callback, you can read the file content with data.Body.toString() you would then append "BAR" to it and then overwrite the object (save to the same file) using same bucket name and key name you received from the event handler with the new string.

Comment: I think this will be quite slow if the file is large